# Ajustar texto dentro de un boton

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

CSS Tengo un boton que tiene un texto bastante largo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando la pantalla cambia de tamaño (se hace mas pequeña), oculta parte del texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que se vaya ajustando al ancho y se despliegue en varias lineas (las que necesite) sin ocultarse nada del texto, no se si me explico bien.
He probado varias propiedades CSS sin éxito, agradecería un poco de ayuda. Gracias

He probado con la propiedad CSS:

- word-wrap: normal | break-word | initial | inherit;
- display: inline | block | flex | inline-block | inline-flex | initial | inherit
- overflow-x: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit

El texto lo inserto mediante jquery:

```
var texto = l.BTN_TEC;
texto += "<br /><h6 style='color: red; margin: 0;'> " + l.TEXT_BTN_TEC + "</h6>";
$("#showTecnicosBtn").html(texto);
```

Comment: Hola Tripossi. Puedes mostrar esas varias propiedades que has probado sin exito ?  Has de añadir un [mcve] . Mira [ask] para más información .Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo que puedes copiar para que veas con que propiedad css solucionas tu problema:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<style>
#b1{
    white-space: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id='b1'>
    <p>Este es un texto largo que puede estar dentro del botón</p>
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

*En cuanto al tamaño del botón si deseas utilizas el **framework Bootstrap** para apoyarte en cuanto a responsive para que tu botón adopte diferentes tamaños en cuanto a distintas resoluciones de dispositivos.*

Comment: Gracias compañero!! Eso es lo que buscaba

Comment: De nada!! Aquí estamos para ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Trata esto,

Bueno no conozco tu manera de escribir tu hoja de estilo pero me atrevo a responder esta pregunta y espero que te funcione

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">

    @media(max-width:960px){
        .content {  
            width: 960px;
        }
    }

    @media(max-width:860px){
            .content {  
            width: 860px;
        }
    }

    .content {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float: left;width: 100%;">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Show Techs</p>

            <p>Clearly print your name below ONLY if you have reviewthe information above and understand:</p>
            <p>1) The scope oif work</p>
            <p>2) The hazards to which you will be exposed and</p>
            <p>3) Te mitigations for those hazads</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Solo usa los media para cada ajuste de pantalla, espero que te funcione

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero lo he solucionado con el comentario de arriba.